# Position absolute inside relative body not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3 to create the layout, I'm not sure if that's relevant. The html/body element is set with height: 100%, I even put min-height: 100% on the body, and the body is set to position relative.

```
         html, body {
          height: 100%; 
          margin: 0; 
          padding: 0; 
      }

          body {
          min-height: 100%; 
          font-size: 16px;
          background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232);
          font-family: Calibri;
          position: relative;
      }
```

Inside the body, on the level under it, is my footer, positioned absolutely with bottom: 0. However, it won't go to the bottom of the page, no matter how bad I want it to.

```
          .footer {
          color: white; 
          background: url(Images/images/footer_bg.gif) repeat-x; 
          padding-top: 10px;
          padding-bottom: 9px; 
          padding-left: 30%; 
      }

      .footerContainer {
          width: 100%; 
          margin: 0; 
          padding: 0; 
          margin-top: 60px; 
          position: absolute;
          right: 0; 
          left: 0; 
      }
```

The footer is a direct child of the body, that is, it's not hiding inside anything else at all. Here's the markup for the footer:

```
<div class="container footerContainer">
<div class="row footer">
    <div class="col-md-12"><p>Content</p></div>
</div>
```

As I said previously, this isn't inside any other divs, just the body. What could the problem be here?

Comment: Could you create a JSFiddle? Use the DOM inspector to verify that the height:100% is actually working. Normally I use a pretty annoying way of keeping footers at the bottom, but Bootstrap has this nice example: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/sticky-footer.html

Comment: I don't see any `bottom:0` on your code sample This is just fine http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/2282/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `bottom:0;` in your sample. Which seems to be the issue.

```
.footerContainer {
   width: 100%; 
   margin: 0; 
   padding: 0; 
   margin-top: 60px; 
   position: absolute;
   border:1px solid;
   bottom:0;
}
```

**Here is a Demo with your code: (*using bootstrap 3*)**

http://jsfiddle.net/n6ypb/3/